# Css paragraph bottom to top

Tags: css

Is is possible with CSS to flow text in a paragraph from the bottom of the paragraph to the top of the paragraph? The text should fill the bottom line of the paragraph first.

Normal behaviour:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et laoreet 
libero. Nulla viverra vehicula pharetra. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante 
ipsum primis in faucibus.
```

What I'm looking for:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor 
sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et laoreet libero. Nulla viverra 
vehicula pharetra. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
```

Comment: logically, I don't think it's possible but more important question: why you want this? why changing how text works?

Comment: @Temani Afif It's for text on big block-buttons (think windows 8 block design), when the text doesn't fit the button's width,.

Comment: Unless there is a *magic* CSS feature that I don't know, it would be tedious to do such thing even with scripting.

Comment: Givin your post history I'm pretty confident it doesn't exist then. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @Frank It seems you need to limit words per line for that you need to add JS. I don't think that is possible with css. Or you may add `<br />` tags manually.

BTW For more text on some button mostly `text-overflow: ellipsis;` is used and add detail or full text in tittle.

Answer (score 0):

have you already tried to use Css Grid? You could create different paragraphs and size the rows accordingly. Probably not the best solution in terms of additional markup but might achieve what you are trying to do?